# python-fortran integration: callback comparison between f2py and ctypes

Tags: python-3.x, fortran, ctypes, f2py

I found an instructive example in : https://numpy.org/devdocs/f2py/python-usage.html#call-back-arguments.
Here the fortran routine:

```
C FILE: CALLBACK.F
  SUBROUTINE FOO(FUN,R)
  EXTERNAL FUN
  INTEGER I
  REAL*8 R, FUN
Cf2py intent(out) r
  R = 0D0
  DO I=-5,5
     R = R + FUN(I)
  ENDDO
  END
C END OF FILE CALLBACK.F
```

This can be compiled with the comand  *f2py -c -m callback callback.f*
and called with the python code:

```
import callback
print(callback.foo.__doc__)
def f(i):
    return i * i
print(callback.foo(f))
```

Everything works fine. Now, I would like to repeat the test using ctypes.
I can compile easily the fortran source with: *gfortran -shared callback.f -o callback.dll*
and I can load the library with:

```
import ctypes as ct
import numpy as np
# import the dll
fortlib = ct.CDLL('callback.dll')
```

**Questions:**

- How can I call the foo function in the dll coming from ctypes like I
  did with the code compiled with f2py?
- How I can interface the two
  variables (pointer to function and pointer to real) required?

Thanks in advance. Gianmarco

*Platform: Anaconda python 3.7.6, Mingw-64 on Windows 10*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good programming style dictates us to never use single-character variable names. A modern Fortran-2008 implementation of your Fortran subroutine would be something similar to the following:

```
module foo_mod

    use iso_c_binding, only: RK => c_double, IK => c_int32_t
    implicit none

    abstract interface
        function getFunVal_proc(inputInteger) result(funVal) bind(C)
            import :: RK, IK
            implicit none
            integer(IK), intent(in), value :: inputInteger
            real(RK) :: funVal
        end function getFunVal_proc
    end interface

contains

    subroutine getFoo(getFunValFromC,outputReal) bind(C,name="getFoo")
        !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: getFoo
        use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_funptr, c_f_procpointer
        implicit none
        type(c_funptr), intent(in), value   :: getFunValFromC
        procedure(getFunVal_proc), pointer  :: getFunVal
        real(RK), intent(out)               :: outputReal
        integer(IK)                         :: indx

        ! associate the input C procedure pointer to a Fortran procedure pointer
        call c_f_procpointer(cptr=getFunValFromC, fptr=getFunVal)

        outputReal = 0._RK
        do indx = -5,5
            write(*,"(*(g0,:,' '))") "value of indx from inside Fortran: ", indx
            outputReal = outputReal + getFunVal(indx)
        end do

        write(*,"(*(g0,:,' '))") "value of outputReal from inside Fortran: ", outputReal

        ! nullify the Fortran pointer
        nullify(getFunVal)

    end subroutine getFoo

end module foo_mod
```

This looks rather verbose, but it is far better than F77. We live in the 21 century, after all. Then you would compile this Fortran code via Intel ifort, for example, like,

```
ifort /dll /threads /libs:static foo_mod.f90 /exe:foo.dll
```

Then, you would call `getFoo()` from the generated DLL `foo.dll` like in the following Python script,

```
import ctypes as ct
import numpy as np

# This is the Python callback function to be passed to Fortran
def getSquare(inputInteger):
    print("value of indx received by getSquare() inside Python: ",inputInteger)
    return np.double(inputInteger**2)

# define ctypes wrapper function, with the proper result and argument types
getFunVal_proc =    ct.CFUNCTYPE( ct.c_double                  # callback (python) function result
                                , ct.c_int32                   # callback (python) function input integer argument
                                )
getSquare_pntr = getFunVal_proc(getSquare)

libpath = "foo.dll"
try:

    # open DLL
    foolib = ct.CDLL(libpath)

except Exception as e:

    import logging
    logger = logging.Logger("catch_all")
    logger.error(e, exc_info=True)

# define getFoo's interface from Fortran dll

foolib.getFoo.restype = None # return type of the Fortran subroutine/function
foolib.getFoo.argtypes =    [ getFunVal_proc            # procedure
                            , ct.POINTER(ct.c_double)   # real64 return value
                            , ]

outputReal = ct.c_double(0.)
foolib.getFoo   ( getSquare_pntr
                , ct.byref(outputReal)
                )
print("value of outputReal received in Python: ", np.double(outputReal))
```

Running this script would yield something like the following,

```
In [1]: run main.py
value of indx from inside Fortran:  -5
value of indx received by getSquare() inside Python:  -5
value of indx from inside Fortran:  -4
value of indx received by getSquare() inside Python:  -4
value of indx from inside Fortran:  -3
value of indx received by getSquare() inside Python:  -3
value of indx from inside Fortran:  -2
value of indx received by getSquare() inside Python:  -2
value of indx from inside Fortran:  -1
value of indx received by getSquare() inside Python:  -1
value of indx from inside Fortran:  0
value of indx received by getSquare() inside Python:  0
value of indx from inside Fortran:  1
value of indx received by getSquare() inside Python:  1
value of indx from inside Fortran:  2
value of indx received by getSquare() inside Python:  2
value of indx from inside Fortran:  3
value of indx received by getSquare() inside Python:  3
value of indx from inside Fortran:  4
value of indx received by getSquare() inside Python:  4
value of indx from inside Fortran:  5
value of indx received by getSquare() inside Python:  5
value of outputReal from inside Fortran:  110.0000000000000
value of outputReal received in Python:  110.0
```

The above Python script might again look rather verbose compared to your F2PY code. But it is far more professional, modern, and standard-compliant, both with Python and Fortran standards than your implementation.

footnote: Intel ifort is available free of charge to all students, teachers, and open-source developers on Windows, Linux, and Mac platforms. This does not mean that gfortran is not good. But in my opinion, using gcc on Windows OS is in general no better than a never-ending nightmare (I have no affiliations with Intel, just a user).

Comment: Thanks for your answer that I going to test. Just to show my reason: Fortran is one of the oldest language and a lot of valuable scientific and technical code was done in the past. The value of the code is not in the code itself but in the science that promoted it (chemistry, physic, engineering). The reason I am interested in this procedure it is not to write code in the old fashion but it is to make some useful code still alive in modern enviroment.  I suppose I am not alone since the example I present comes  from the last documentation of numpy.

Comment: I realized your intentions after I posted my answer. But I'd still strongly recommend using Fortran 2008 or newer instead of F77. A good reference for modern Fortran is the book by Metcalf et al "Modern Fortran Explained". Searching the web will direct you to the book. Also, if the code above answers your question, please accept it as the answer so that others with similar questions can find it more easily. Fortran resources are by themselves already scattered and hard-to-find. thanks.